# How do you dynamically create a dropdown list in Google sheets using values from an array or perhaps an object?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

I am looking to create a dropdown list with some data validation (set list of items may only be entered). anyone know how to do this using apps script?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. StackOverflow is not a free coding website.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use the class [data validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation).
- Specifically, the method [setDataValidation(rule)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setDataValidation(DataValidation)) and
  [newDataValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app.html#newDataValidation()) to set-up a validation rule.
- The validation rule for dropdowns is [requireValueInRange(range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInRange(Range)).

*Sample:*

```
function myDropdown(){
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var validationRange=sheet.getRange("A1:A3");
  var validationRule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build()
  sheet.getRange("B1").setDataValidation(validationRule);
}
```